# fprintf not working properly in GNU-octave

Tags: if-statement, file-io, printf, octave, gnu

There's this piece of code with me, which.
1. opens two files,"blue.csv","red.csv".
2. calculates the value and based on if-else statement, prints the output to the corresponding file.

```
fp1 = fopen('red.csv','w');
fp2 = fopen('blue.csv','w');

for x = 0:100:2500, 
    for y = 0:100:2500,
        vector = [x , y]
        vara = gOfX(vector,mu1,finalcovariance) ;
        varb = gOfX(vector,mu2,finalcovariance) ;
        if vara < varb
            fprintf(fp2,'%d,%d\n',x,y);
            fprintf('vara-varb is -------negative\n ');         
        else 
            fprintf('%d,%d\n',x,y);
            fprintf(fp1,'%d,%d\n',x,y);
            fprintf('vara-varb is ---------------------positive\n ');
        endif;
   endfor
endfor
```

The problem is, the `fprintf(fp1,'%d,%d\n',x,y);` statement in `else` condition is not working,i.e., I am unable to get anything in the file specified by`fp1` although the statements above and below are perfectly working fine(`gOfX` is therefore working fine too).

I have tried changing the file pointers etc. but none of that worked.
Moreover, if I change the `if vara < varb` condition to `if vara > varb`, then I don't get anything printed into file pointed by `fp2`( thus to me,it seems the problem with `>` part).

Any solution could drastically save my time in finishing my assignment. 
Thanks !

Comment: you need to `fclose` the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Octave's [fflush](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/fflush.html) to flush the buffer

Don't forget to close your files using [fclose](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/fclose.html).

Comment: @me.ydv.5 More importantly, he needs to _close_ the file!